# Как правильно писать инициалы?

Tags: орфография

Сталкиваюсь с тем, что сейчас все чаще, подписывая какую-либо цитату, указывают не имя-отчество автора, а только имя, например, "А. Пушкин". Я так предполагаю, что делается это в угоду Западу, где нет понятия отчеств.
Но вообще, как новые правила требуют писать инициалы авторов: с именем-отчеством или без? Потому что, если даже взять наших классиков, кого-то мы привыкли называть только по имени, например, Владимир Маяковский, Сергей Есенин, а кого-то исключительно по имени-отчеству: Александр Сергеевич Пушкин, Михаил Юрьевич Лермонтов и т.д.

Comment: А что, есть новые правила?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас
 я вообще наблюдаю тенденцию на исчезновение отчеств. У старшего 
поколения были распространены обращения только по отчеству, *Ильинична, 
Иваныч*, а сейчас все большую популярность набирает форма на "Вы", но 
лишь с именем, - "Как ваше, Надежда, самочувствие?" По моим наблюдениям 
из здравствующих медийных персон  в СМИ с отчеством остались лишь 
президент, Жириновский и Познер (что интересно, все Владимиры), отец и сын Масляковы. Как с 
отчеством так и без называют Медведева, Зюганова, Якубовича и Пугачеву , а у всех 
остальных отчеств почти не упоминают.

Подобное явление, по всей видимости, вызвано следующими факторами:

1. Всеобщая "фамилиезация", Еще в начале ХХ века фамилии были далеко не у
    всех и их функцию во многом выполняли отчества.
2. Влияние западных языков.

Что касается конкретных норм, то принято или указывать инициалы - *А. С.
 Пушкин*, или писать имя полностью - *Сергей Есенин*, хотя и инициалы 
без отчества вне официальной документации ошибкой быть не должны.

Comment: Думаю, что это просто "косят" под Запад. Им кажется, что, обращаясь по имени без отчества, они сразу становятся американцами. А уж, если при этом кока-колу попкорном заедать, то вообще...  
По-русски это называется "холуйство", а по-украински "як у панiв".